# C# ServiceStack OrmLite GetDialectProvider.ToAddForeignKeyStatement

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

Just recently tried OrmLite for MySql in a C# console project:

I'm loving it, since it's easy to implement with MySql, in contrast to Entity Framework. However I'm trying to enable automatic updates of the database schema from my model. I extended the code given in the answers in:

[With OrmLite, is there a way to automatically update table schema when my POCO is modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142433/with-ormlite-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-table-schema-when-my-poco-i)

And came up with a solution that can add and delete columns in your database schema, depending on the model. Works pretty good, and utilizes a lot of the features OrmLite.ModelDefinition gives.

See the solution here:
https://github.com/contradel/Extending-NServiceKit.OrmLite

However I can't get it to automatically create foreign keys with GetDialectProvider.ToAddForeignKeyStatement(). And I can't find any documentation. Does anyone know how it works?

I would like to be able to do this:

```
public class Order
{
    //Try to add or comment out properties here, SQL will be generated automatic
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; } //pk
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Customer))]      //Creates Foreign Key
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
foreach (FieldDefinition field in missingOnDb)
            {
                //if (field != ForeignKey)
                var addSql = string.Format(db.GetDialectProvider().ToAddColumnStatement(typeof(T), field));
                //else
                //addSql = db.GetDialectProvider().ToAddForeignKeyStatement(??,??,??,??,??);

                Console.WriteLine(addSql);
                db.ExecuteSql(addSql);
            }
```